# Selenium ChromeDriver python not waiting for page to load

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium 3.11, with chromedriver 2.37, chrome 65.0, and python 3.6.2. I recently updated my chromedriver from 2.36 to 2.37 due to receiving the following error,

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'.
```

I then upgraded my chromedriver and now I am running into an issue with selenium not waiting for the page to load and receiving errors such as;

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtUserName"}

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
```

I have a feeling this is due to the new chromedriver because if I use IE then I have no issues. I know I can add WebdriverWaits but I do not want to go through all of my code and add 100+ explicit waits. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit
I have continued trying to find the issue, and it seems the like the web page I am trying to hit is part of the issue. The webpage I am trying to access is not a registered webpage, therefore I need to get a certificate before accessing the page. Before chromedriver 2.37 my script was running fine.

Comment: No need to add 100+ waits throughout your code. Just put         `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)` after driver creation. It will wait up to 10 seconds before throwing error. You can change 10 to whatever as per your requirement. This may not be the solution. But at least it would help you to debug either the issue is with chromedriver or something else..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately that did not help. Without putting in an explicit wait I get the "NoSuchElementException"